# installing zf2 on ubuntu server 12.04.01 LTS

Tags: zend-framework2, ubuntu-server

Trying to install ZF2 on my ubuntu server using

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && ./composer.phar create-project zendframework/skeleton-application /var/www/skeleton-app dev-master
```

I've also tried to add `@dev` in the end and I keep on getting the following error:

"could not find package zendframework/skeleton-application/var/www/skeleton-app with stability stable."

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication#using-composer-recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Xerkus

From https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication#using-composer-recommended

Should have read more about it i guess

Comment: This usually does not really work due to several (!) errors. Currently there's not stable version available (!!), and sometimes the folder "is not empty" (yes, because composer.phar is in there). The install tutorial of ZF2 is a huge piece of crap. I wonder that the ZF2 team dont realize...

Answer (score 7):

Add `-sdev`

So it became

```
php composer.phar create-project -sdev --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add --stability="dev" to your second command.

The command I used is as follows:

php /path/to/phar/composer.phar create-project --stability="dev" --repository-url="https://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application skel-app/